# phpMyAdmin: Can't import huge database file, any suggestions?

Tags: upload, phpmyadmin, size

I recently got a new computer, so I thought I'd move all my web projects over. Moving the files was easy, however, moving the database seems to be a bit harder. I exported ALL databases using phpMyAdmin, and saved it to localhost.sql. Then I tried to import it on my new computer also using phpMyAdmin, and I get the error:

```
No data to import. Either no filename was sent or the filesize exceeded the maximum allowed size. See FAQ 1.16. (This was translated from Swedish)
```

I took a look at the FAQ, as advised. And they mentioned a tool called BigDump. So I downloaded it, and after looking at the settings you need to run it I realised that I CAN'T USE THAT EITHER. Why? Because it requires a connection to one specific database. I'm trying to import MANY databases at once. So, no success there.

I also tried setting PHP's upload_max_filesize (and the other one's mentioned in the FAQ) to something like 999. That doesn't seem to work either for some reason. I did restart all services before I ran it again.

I should mention that I used XAMPP on my old computer, and I switched to WAMP on my new one. That shouldn't matter though, right? As both "packages" uses phpMyAdmin and apache.

Any suggestions on how to bypass this nightmare?

Comment: whats the size of ur database?

Comment: You made upload_max_size to just 999 or 999M?, just wanted to confirm.

Comment: Sorry, i set it to 999M. The filesize is 4,68 MB.

Comment: Please use phpinfo (http://help.rackspacecloud.com/article.php?id=082) and verify that your changes in php.ini actually took place. May be you changed the wrong php.ini (and you can see the path of the php.ini in effect from phpinfo also).  Secondly, if you make any syntax error in php.ini file, the configuration set there will be ignored and default configuration will be applied (which AFAIK sets upload limite to 2MB)

Comment: @Sawar; why the h*ll are there several php.ini's? The issue was i changed the wrong file. I can import it now, however i'm facing another problem now.`Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema'`. Half of the datbases were importet, but it got stuck there.

Comment: @qwerty: WAMP is not a single software. They took apache, mysql, php (and other tools like phpMyAdmins) and combined. They left the original php.ini that came with php intact, created another php.ini in the apache directory to use for WAMP. Now, you can create another php.ini for your IIS and use single installation of php in both IIS and apache (with different configs!)
You should NOT had exported the information_schema DB from the old server. This DB contains metadata about server and other DB, tables etc.When you import the data,metadata is created in new server.So, reexport without this DB

Answer (score 53):

**HowTo**

Make sure you change both *"post_max_size"* and *"upload_max_filesize"* in your *"php.ini"* (which is located where your *"php.exe"* is).

The following example allows you to upload and import 128MB sql files:

```
post_max_size=128M
upload_max_filesize=128M
```

Restart Apache and you're all set.

**Alternatives**

An alternative way to work around the problem is to use the command line. But it's a workaround, and as ugly as workarounds get:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\mysql.exe -u root -p db_name < C:\some_path\your_sql_file.sql
```

As you're not using the server but the command line, upload and POST sizes don't matter. That's why I call this a *"workaround"*, since it doesn't actually solve your problem.

Comment: Good answer (should be accepted by OP): the command line approach worked for me but make sure that the mysql max_allowed_packet setting (in my.cnf file or my.ini file in mysql settings folder on your system) is larger than the size of the .sql file that you want to import/upload. For example my .sql was about 250Mb, so I set max_allowed_packet to be 1024M (well above that) just to be sure! Presumably max_allowed_packet  would also apply to using phpmyadmin because although you must set post_max_size and upload_max_filesize, you may still get an error if max_allowed_packet is not also set.

Comment: If you see "mysql server has gone away" with error code 2006 then this can be caused by max_allowed_packet being smaller than the file you want to import/upload - so my above comment should remedy this for you.

Answer (score 21):

Others are always trying to reconfigure the php.ini file but for me I think the best practice is use your MYSQL console because it really saves your time.

Here are the step by step guide to the MYSQL Console:

Open your MYSQL Console then run it.

Type:

**mysql> use database_name;**

**mysql> source location_of_your_file;**

location_of_your_file should look like C:\mydb.sql

so **the command is mysql>source C:\mydb.sql;**

This kind of importing sql dump is very helpful for BIG SQL FILE.

I copied my file mydb.sql to directory C: .**It should be capital C: in order to run** because it will give you a mysql error or syntax error

Answer (score 9):

in wamp server:

1. Open config.inc.php file in the path "C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin" and set/add this line. $cfg['UploadDir'] = ‘upload’;
2. Restart all services
3. Now create upload folder inside your phpmyadmin(C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.0.4\upload) folder and put your .sql file in upload folder.
4. Now open phpmyadmin in browser, go to import. You can see the file in dropdown just below browse button with that upload directory folder and files.
5. Select it and Go…

Comment: this works for me, I don't know why it is not working the other way.

Comment: didn't know about this function, very useful when on a shared hosting without permission to change PHP settings or have shell access.

Answer (score 8):

Make changes in `xampp\php\php.ini`

Find:

```
post_max_size       = 8M
upload_max_filesize = 2M
max_execution_time  = 30
max_input_time      = 60
memory_limit        = 8M
```

Change to:

```
post_max_size       = 750M
upload_max_filesize = 750M
max_execution_time  = 5000
max_input_time      = 5000
memory_limit        = 1000M
```

Answer (score 3):

You can import from the command line - something like `mysql < databasedump.sql` (depending on the OS).

Comment: I thought of that aswell, however, i am no commandline-ninja. How do i specify in which folder the file is? Would it work if i just moved it to the same folder as the mysql.exe file? Thanks!

Comment: You need have the file in your current working directory - or use the full pathname on the command line.  (Sorry... I run linux; don't know the exact commands on windoze.)

Comment: Alright, thanks! I got phpMyAdmin to work though, i edited the wrong php.ini file. (kind of embarassing) Still very good to know though, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Follow this step to dump huge database:**

1) Download php script **BigDump.php** from http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/

2) Move your **bigdump.php** and your **databasedump.sql** in projects folder (htdocs or www).

3) open **bigdump.php** file and edit bellow section:

```
$db_server   = 'localhost';
$db_name     = '';
$db_username = '';
$db_password = ''; 

$filename           = '.sql';
```

4) open **bigdump.php** in browser and click on import link.

Answer (score 1):

This will import your large sql file within few seconds:

```
e:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysql -u root -h localhost < verybigsqlfile.sql
```

Don't use phpmyadmin to import large sql files. If you are using mysql online, then take the mysql console access.

Comment: @CodeWithCoffee that's because you must select a database before run commands on it: use databasenamehere

Answer (score 1):

compress sql file (only gzip, bzip2, zip) and import it. compressing test files like db csv file will reduce file size dramatically (~ 11 mb to 2 mb) and phpmyadmin import engine cand etect compressed data

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but.. 
I came up with this problem long ago.
Either I used the console to execute dump sql file.
Or I use [adminer](http://www.adminer.org/) as an alternative to PHPmyAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the my.ini file

in the [mysqld] section add the following lines

```
wait_timeout=28800
interactive_timeout = 28800
max_allowed_packet=32M
```

Restart the mysql

open the dump.sql file 
add the following lines

```
use mydbname
```

Go to the mysql folder and run this command

```
mysql -u root -h localhost < dump.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

phpmyadmin has the ability to read from the harddrive as well - upload the dump and use this feature. However, I would strongly advise you to the from the console if possible. It's way faster as php doesn't have to process the file first and it gets loaded directly into the server.

Comment: That's what i did. I'm running WAMP locally now, so just tried to use phpMyAdmin's upload funtion to import it. The console sounds like a good idea, however, i'm not a ninja in that area. Read awm's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having a very large database uploading though the web interface will be limited to HTTP maximum HTTP request size

Edit the `PHP.ini` to increase the upload limit

*find  this line*

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; File Uploads ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
file_uploads = On

; Temporary directory for HTTP uploaded files (will use system default if not
; specified).
;upload_tmp_dir =

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = ??M **<--- change here ....**
```

Then restart the server

```
/sbin/service httpd restart
```

or use directadmin to restart the http service

Comment: Would that be the "post_max_size" setting? I changed that aswell.

Comment: And thinking about it, it should accept this file anyway. I mean, it's not a huge file, it's just a huge database. The filsize is about 4 MB.

Comment: (Max: 128 MiB) PHP myadmin uploader says check it

Comment: check this generate the SQL file and execute queries little by little but will not be really practical !

Comment: Alright, mine actually says 2048 KiB. (that's 2 MB, right?) What setting do i have to change?

Comment: I got it working, but i didn't need to change the upload_max_filesize. phpMyAdmin uses a function that splits the import into pieces when the filesize is near the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SQLYog](http://www.soft82.com/categories/Windows/Developer_Tools) for db operations it is the best choice for professional. By using SQLYog you can import **nGB {n->finite_size}** of sql db.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to change the allowed size, but that didn't fixed the problem.

However, there's a folder called "**uploaddir**", in my particular case, located in:

> EasyPHP\modules\phpmyadmin\uploaddir

I put the SQL file there, and then went back to the "Import" tab of PHP My Admin. 
There's an option that allowed me to upload files that were already located in "uploaddir" folder; and they have no limit.

I'm using Windows and EasyPHP 12.1

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is that just download & install "MySql Workbench" software, its gui based and easy to use.I have recently import 300mb size mysql database.

Answer (score 0):

If you'r on linux, you can go to terminal and after connect to mysql and select database, simply type:

```
\. /path/to/database/database.sql
```

Answer (score -1):

sql resubmit link

[image: 1]

You can resubmit your SQL file again until database not fully uploaded

Comment: Share more details on the process, this looks like trial and error method. I believe you using the CMD for loading the file would be a better approach.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).